# Puppeteer's page.evaluate() always returns empty object when used in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, puppeteer, evaluate

I am trying to create UI in Electron for scraper in Puppeteer. 
Every time I use page.evaluate() it returns an empty object [object Object], 
here is an example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://google.com/", {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    timeout: 90000
  });

  const length = await page.evaluate(`selector => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).length;
  }`, 'div');

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();

  return length;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", async function() {
  const divs_len =  await scrape();
  const par = document.querySelector('#par');
  par.innerText = divs_len;
});

// par shows [object Object]
```

**EDIT**

I have used the following resource to fix the sample code: 
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4221#issuecomment-478780545

And here is the working version:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://google.com/", {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    timeout: 90000
  });

  const functionToBeEvaluated = selector => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).length;
  }

  const result = await page.evaluate('(' + functionToBeEvaluated.toString() + ')("div");');

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();

  return result;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", async function() {
  const divs_len =  await scrape();
  const par = document.querySelector('#par');
  par.innerText = divs_len;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `page.evaluate()` argument, you can use a function expression that will be called or a string with a direct code that will be executed. If you send a function expression as a string, `page.evaluate()` returns just a reference to this very function which becomes an empty object as functions are not serializable. Try this:

```js
  const length = await page.evaluate(selector => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).length;
  }, 'div');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason for using a string is because otherwise I get the following error: `Error: Passed function is not well-serializable!`

Comment: Sorry( Maybe this is an Electron quirk.